# IHS - SSL mutual authentication for only some pages

Tags: ssl, https, certificate, ssl-certificate

I'd like to authenticate my clients using SSL client certs, but just for some urls within an application? So I'd like:

site1/url1 does not ask for client certificate
site1/url2 requires that the client is using a valid client cert

With Apache you can do it with SSLClientVerify, but this option does not work with IHS. I have checked some URLs, but none of them answers my problem.

https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/246111/ihs-ssl-mutual-authentication-for-only-some-pages.html

Any clue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It was not possible to do it with IHS, I changed it to Apache.